# How to write this string in a proper way

Tags: php, string, syntax-error

I want to store a javascript onclick function code into a string first and then i need to pass it in a radio button.

My sting variable is:

```
$jsFunc = "onclick=\"javascript:showHide(this.value, \'$arrFlipEntities[$field_id]\');\"";
```

I want to use this variable like dis:

```
$strCode .= "<input {$jsFunc} type=\"radio\" name=\"{$field_name}\" id=\"{$option}\" value=\"{$option}\" checked=\"checked\"/><label for=\"{$option}\">{$option}</label>";
```

But it is giving this output, when i viewed the source code:

```
<input onclick="javascript:showHide(this.value, \'bas_link\');" type="radio" name="bas_type" id="Yes" value="Yes" checked="checked">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when ' is in two ",it doesn't need \

```
$jsFunc = "onclick=\"javascript:showHide(this.value, '$arrFlipEntities[$field_id]')\"";
$strCode .= "<input {$jsFunc} type=\"radio\" name=\"{$field_name}\" id=\"{$option}\" value=\"{$option}\" checked=\"checked\"/><label for=\"{$option}\">{$option}</label>";
```

Comment: that will get:<input onclick="javascript:showHide(this.value, 'bas_link');" type="radio" name="bas_type" id="Yes" value="Yes" checked="checked">

Comment: i'm not familiar with js,if i was wrong ,tell me what you want

Comment: Thannx.. .fr quick reply. I was not knowing abt dis.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$jsFunc = "onclick=\"javascript:showHide(this.value, '".$arrFlipEntities[$field_id]."');\"";

$strCode .= "<input {$jsFunc} type=\"radio\" name=\"{$field_name}\" id=\"{$option}\" value=\"{$option}\" checked=\"checked\"/><label for=\"{$option}\">{$option}</label>";
```

Answer (score 1):

I prefer the single quote method like so:

```
$jsFunc = 'onClick="javascript:showHide(this.value, '.$arrFlipEntities[$field_id].');"';

$strCode .= '<input '.$jsFunc.' type="radio" name="'.$field_name.'" id="'.$option.'" value="'.$option.'" checked="checked"/><label for="'.$option.'">'.$option.'</label>';
```

Comment: Thannx.. .fr quick reply. It helped me.

Comment: you can help me by marking my answer as useful (arrow up)... as I said, I find using the single quote method a lot easier than the double quote... or maybe I'm just used to it.... cheers and good luck on your path to development :)

Comment: Im new to this site, il surely mark it once il get 15repuations. Rite now i have 14.

Comment: gotcha :) --- I enjoy helping fellow Devs.... been in the game for over 14 years and I know how frustrating it can be :) --- If I can prevent you from banging your head on the wall in frustration then I'll gladly do so :).. btw, I upped your question so your rep should be increased

Comment: Yes.. i did it for your answer as well. Thanx again.

Answer (score 0):

```
$jsFunc = "onclick=\"javascript:showHide(this.value, \'$arrFlipEntities[$field_id]\');\"";
```

Should be:

```
$jsFunc = "onclick=\"javascript:showHide(this.value, '".$arrFlipEntities[$field_id]."');\"";
```

Single and double quotes don't get escaped when they are wrapped by the other. Also you can't access an array like that inside double quotes, only works for variables like $var = "$myVar";